# Change View in Multitasking Switcher not working on iPhone6

Tags: ios, swift, snapshot, iphone-6

I have to change the snapshots and multitasking view of only some views that contains confidential data. For that I use the following code, which is called when *NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive* is triggered. My problem is that on iPhone 6(11.1.1) it does not work when it goes to the multitasking switcher (*app switcher*). (I have tried on iPhone 6s 11.1.1 and it worked perfectly), also in more advanced devices. In iPhone 5 it works 9 of 10 times. But in iPhone 6 it never works. (When I bring the App to foreground again it shows the LaunchScreenViewController for just a few and then it disappears). I have checked that the code inside completion closure is called before change the state to inactive, but it does not present the LaunchView.

I do not want to call the app delegate or Window from a viewController, I also have tried to get the viewController loaded in a static var and just present it, and it didn’t work neither. Moreover, I tried to add a subview to the navigation controller but it does not work neither in the iPhone 6. (I have tried with 2 iPhones 6). When the application goes to the background it works fine, also If I am in the app switcher (the launch View is not shown, but if I reopen another application and then I go again to the App switcher, now the application shows the Launch View.

```
let overlayVC = LaunchScreenViewController(showsSpinner: false)
        self.navigationController?.present(overlayVC, animated: false,completion: { [weak self] in
            self?.setObserverApplicationIsActive()
        })
```

Have you dealt with this problem? I also tried to add a blur effect but it didn't work.

Edit: If you run a video on youtube and change to the multitask switcher, the video continues playing. So I do not know why on iPhone 6 it does not present a new viewController.